# Call simple function with Route Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, routes, django-queryset

Its a simple question, but I want to understand it.

I have a simple api rest in django rest framework

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'productos', ChelaViewSet)
```

That gives me my data json from my model, it's working fine.

Class ChelaViewSet:

```
class ChelaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = ChelaSerializer
queryset = Chela.objects.all()
```

I just want to call a class with simple function like "hello world" from my route, when I put the URL print "Hello world" in console, no more, without queryset etc...

What can I do?

Ty

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override whichever method of `ModelViewSet` the route that you want to print something for uses.

From the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset):

> The actions provided by the `ModelViewSet` class are `.list()`, `.retrieve()`, `.create()`, `.update()`, `.partial_update()`, and `.destroy()`.

So if you want to `print` something for the `list` view, you can do:

```
class ChelaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = ChelaSerializer
  queryset = Chela.objects.all()

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("hello")
    # Call the original list method from ModelViewSet
    return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[This](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html) is also a handy website that you can use to inspect the code of DRF's views and serializers.

Comment: wow, it works, ty! but... Can I call a function by route in a class without derivated? I mean... class ChelaViewSet(): only with print. No queryset, simple class.

Comment: Nope, if you just put a `print` statement in the class definition, it will be called when the class is defined. If you want the `print` to be called when a route is run, you'll need to put it in a method and to do that you'll need to override the class.